# error trying to connect a PHP script to a Host gator MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error I receive when I look in my webpage.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'locahost' (0)
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'locahost' (0)' in /home2/ecuanaso/public_html/daveswebapps.us/functions.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home2/ecuanaso/public_html/daveswebapps.us/functions.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', '***', '***') #1 /home2/ecuanaso/public_html/daveswebapps.us/index.php(4): testdb_connect('locahost', '***', '***') #2 {main} thrown in /home2/ecuanaso/public_html/daveswebapps.us/functions.php on line 17
```

This is the script on my functions.php

```
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = "locahost";
/*** mysql username ***/
$username = "***";
/*** mysql password ***/
$password = "***";

function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
global $pdo;
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=***", $username, $password);
 return $dbh;
 }

 try {
 $dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
 echo 'Connected to database';
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`:

Comment: Can the mods remove this before someone hacks daveswebapps.us?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `"root"` as both the username and password to connect to your database. (You've tried to hide this in your code sample by replacing both with `"xxx"`, but it's still visible in your stack trace.) This is almost certainly *not* the correct username and password for your database; contact your hosting provider to get the correct values.

Comment: When I tried to use my cpanel username and password from my hostgator account I still get a fatal error.

    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user

Comment: There is almost certainly a separate username and password you're supposed to use for MySQL. Like I said, **contact your hosting provider** if you don't know what it is.

Comment: Just did call my hosting and they said all the settings are correct. like the hostname, dbname, username and password. They tell me its a developer issue.

Comment: So is there anybody that can help me with this?